# Connection lost to MySQL Server during query

Tags: php, mysql

I have got a problem in mysql:
My PHP gets disconnected from MySQL for a simple query. The error is:

> Lost connection to MySQL server during query.

And it is thrown from :

```
  $stmt->execute();
```

### Here is my PHP code:

```
$app->post('/checkmd5', function() use($app) {
    $data = $app->request()->params();
    $version = $data["VERSION"];
    $md5 = $data["MD5"];

    $stmt = getDb()->prepare("SELECT MD5 FROM UpdateInfo WHERE VersionName = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $version);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows() > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($dbMD5);
        $stmt->fetch();
        if ($md5 == $dbMD5)
        {
            $app->render(200, array("SUCCESS_MD5_MATCH", "VALID" => "true"));
        }
        else
        {
            $app->render(400, array("msg" => "ERROR_NO_MD5_MATCH", "VALID" => "false"));
        }
    }
    else
    {

        $app->render(400, array("msg" => "ERROR_VERSION_STRING_NOT_FOUND", "VALID" => "false", "VERSION" => $version));
    }
});
```

### In PHPMyAdmin it works:

[image: PHPMyAdmin_Output]

### And this is what PHP gives out:

[image: PHP_Api_Output]

Comment: There may be multiple reasons as to why this is happening. Wrong firewal configuration, effectively blocking you out, you exhausting the connection, wrong my.cnf configuration,...

Comment: Check out all those linked questions on the right.

Comment: Mysql works, only this query doesn't. Its weird. Also the MySQL server is localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be solved by simply saving the returnment of getDb() to a variable

Comment: so, once every reference to the db connection is gone, the connection is implicitly closed? and prepared statements does not have any reference to the connection?

Comment: @hanshenrik i think its phps garbage collector which simply closes the connection.